# How to Use Flash and Actionscript to Animate Human Walking

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I want to write a small game using flash and actionscript but I am not sure how to start. The basic element may be a man walking on a surface which I suppose is the fundamental elements for my application. However, as I am new to flash and such a project is just a test for whether I can learn from the internet quickly to master a new language, I suppose that examples are the best. So how can I get a human walking on the ground in 3D example using flash?

Thanks you all for that, I prefer source codes from which I can learn how to build a human model and animates the model using flash and action script.

Comment: what level of "3D" are you looking for? Are you interested in being able to rotate around the model as it walks, or do you just want a pseudo-3d experience where the human looks three dimensional while walking in a 2D plane ( platformer or top-down view )?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, you're not looking for much are you?

What you're describing is quite complicated and made up of skill which are themselves also quite complicated. (I don't know how to play the piano, but could you show me how to play some Rachmaninoff?)

For one thing, the 3D model of the man would most likely need to be created in another program, like blender for instance and imported into Flash.

What I would suggest is starting small and building up the skills that would be required for making something like this. Start with drawing some simple shapes on the screen, then make them move, then make them controllable, then make them interact.  Each one it's own lesson.  Then make a simple 2D game. and go from there.

[Start with something like this.](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/792/1/Drawing-Shapes-with-AS3/Page1.html)

Answer (score 1):

In a symbol make a man with his each hand and leg in different layer and JUST animate body movements of walking(not moving from one place to another). At end and stop of each movement i.e right and left add stop() in frames
Then in main timeline , import symbol from library to stage and then in code snippets>animation>move with keyboard arrows.